# Tooling or method to re-add 'content' to projects utilizing "Package References"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, packagereference

1. A project (original VS format) is converted to *use* Package References. Great.
2. Project References "don't support content". Questionable choice, although not debated here.
3. Some used packages contain "content" and *cannot or will not* be updated to use "content files". Hmm..

*What semi-automated tooling / method can be used to copy the "content" from NuGet dependencies that "don't support contentFiles"<sup>+</sup>?* Only applying to direct packages is fine.

---

<sup>+</sup>Naturally, one could manually open up each individual NuGet file and copy the contents. This question isn't about "why" the switch was made and/or any merits or trade-offs and/or how how packages "should" be authored. The question is about an automated or semi-automated method to be able to restore the "content" into a project's source tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible to use "content"-based NuGet packages with original Visual Studio / MSBuild projects that have been converted to use Package References.**

The presented solution can likely be amended for SDK-style projects as well. The feat is accomplished by utilizing the [`GeneratePathProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) attribute of `PackageReference`<sup>+</sup>. Using the generated `Pkg*` path properties ensures valid paths to the referenced packages. (Note: if a package name contains `.`, replace it with `_` in the `Pkg*` property name.)

First, add a [`GeneratePathProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) to all the packages with content to copy or link.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="bootstrap" GeneratePathProperty="true">
  <Version>Don't ask..</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="AngularJS.Core" GeneratePathProperty="true">
  <Version>..it's not great</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

## "Get the Content"

Depending on needs there are two different approaches presented here. While these approaches can be used together, neither approach should be applied to "content files"-based NuGet packages.

### Approach #1: Copy Content to Project Source

With this approach it's expected that the files are added to source control. The following lines in the project can thus be un-commented (and re-commented) when updating packages to ensure that the newest NuGet package content.

It uses the [`Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019) Task to, well, copy the the content.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <NugetContentToRestore Include="
                         $(Pkgbootstrap)\Content\**\*.*;
                         $(PkgAngularJS_Core)\Content\**\*.*;
                         " />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(NugetContentToRestore)"
        DestinationFiles="@(NugetContentToRestore->'$(ProjectDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

If the ItemGroup is not commented out during normal development, the items will be included in the the project’s solution explorer root, which is a bit ugly. It’s also not possible to detect when "content" has been removed.

### Approach #2: Link in Content

If none of the content is to be copied and/or checked into source control along with the project, it can also be linked in. This approach has the benefit of always linking in the latest content and does not pollute the solution explorer.

A local file explicitly included in the project will take precedence over the linked resources.

#### For a Normal Project (and bin-deployed files)

For a normal project, `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` is sufficient and the linked files will go in the 'bin' output. However, this does not work for a Web Project which only understands files which are physically present in the project tree.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(Pkgbootstrap)\Content\**\*.*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
  <Content Include="$(PkgAngularJS_Core)\Content\**\*.*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

#### For a Web Project (*requires local files*)

For a Web Project, these links must be copied to local files: `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` is not sufficient or required. Packages with content that *should* go into the bin output should use the approach above.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(Pkgbootstrap)\Content\**\*.*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Content>
  <Content Include="$(PkgAngularJS_Core)\Content\**\*.*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then add a target to copy the linked files so they are picked up by the Web Project tooling. See [Copying linked content files at each build using MSBuild](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx). It may be relevant so skip certain links and add source control ignore entries.

```xml
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)"
        DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)"
        SkipUnchangedFiles='true'
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true'
        Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
</Target>
```

---

<sup>+</sup>This works in an up-to-date Visual Studio 2019 environment. It may not work in certain older MSBuild/NuGet configurations as `Pkg*` property generation is required.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer. Anyway, thanks for sharing the solution and let us learn it.

Answer (score -1):

> Tooling or method to re-add 'content' to projects utilizing “Package
> References”

**I am afraid that there is no such tool to make files from content folder into projects with **PackageReference** nuget management format.**

**As** the user of the package, there is currently no tool to copy the files of the **content** folder to the projects with **PackageReference**.

**And** actually, if there is such a tool, it also violates the mechanism of nuget. **All of them are depended on the author of the nuget package rather than the users unless the package is authored by us**

**Suggestion**

So you have to manually unzip the nuget package and copy the files into your project.

And it seems to be a bit complex and if you still want to get a easy way to get what you want, I suggest you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

**And after that**, you could share the link here and anyone who is interested in it will vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. All of these will help get what you want as soon as possible.

Comment: **This question is not soliciting the “spirit” of the PackageReferences or asking about packages with “content files”.** It is a request of how to restore “content”, such as from old NuGet packages that have not been updated. **As noted in the question,** this can be done manually. It seems quite plausible that there exists and automated method to do this manual process in an automated (and largely repeatable) fashion.

Comment: I added #3 for explicitness. This question isn’t about making “content files” to act like “content”. It’s about restoring the “content” provided by older packages.

Comment: I guess I spend a day writing some PowerShell to do the manual steps in an automated manner. It really seems this is not a “novel” ask. I spent a while searching the internet and it’s littered with “justification” without viable solutions.

Comment: It’s also pointless to open up any such request about such tool created by the NuGet team. Since at least 2017 these requests have been closed as “by design” while failing to account for existing, and sometimes required/useful, usages of “content”. If the “choice” is indeed outside of the NuGet scope, it seems reasonable that such a choice would be supported, even if not preferred or in the default execution paths. And.. nope.

Comment: The "MSBuild.NugetContentRestore" packages requires a packages.config, as the premise seems sufficient for the task. Regardless, it's an example of tooling that is almost sufficient.